# How to read JKS file from S3 and decode it for usage in Scala?

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, jks

I'm new to Scala and using the following code to pull a .jks file from AWS S3:

```
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3ClientBuilder
import java.io.File
import java.io.BufferedReader
import java.io.InputStreamReader
import java.io.FileOutputStream
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils

val s3obj = AmazonS3ClientBuilder
  .defaultClient()
  .getObject("bucket", "folder/file")
val bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(s3obj.getObjectContent())
val file = new FileOutputStream("tmp/keystore.jks")
file.write(bytes)

// recommended way to access the .jks file as a parsed file reference.
```

What's the recommended way to parse this binary file (tmp/keystore.jks) for usage as a .jks file from disk after being loaded to disk from AWS S3?

Answer (score 0):

you can import the package `import java.security.KeyStore` and init your ks :

```
val passphrase = ??? // char array
val ksKeys = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS") 
val keystoreResource = this.getClass.getClassLoader.getResourceAsStream("path to keystore") 
ksKeys.load(keystoreResource, passphrase)
```

Comment: Thanks! Going to test this soon.